# error "no_text" at Slack API chat.postMessage even though text attribute is there

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I tried out Slack's Bolt framework for Python. I was experimenting with the Calls API and wanted to post the call to the channel, along with some text. So I used chat.postMessage. However, I get an error ("no_text").

Below is my code (token starred out for security):

```
client.chat_postMessage(
            token="**************",
            channel="general",
            blocks=[
                {
                    "type": "call",
                    "call_id": slackCallId,
                }
            ],
            text="Test of Calls Api"
        )
```

However, in the Slack channel I see this and then call:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    [
        {
            "type": "slackCallId",
            "call_id": "test"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Test of Calls Api"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Tried that, no difference unfortunately.